# Common word for a room like 'office' or 'study'

Tags: single-word-requests

What do people commonly call a room (in a residential detached house) with a desk, a chair, a computer, pen and paper, maybe a few bookshelves, etc.?  You know, a quiet place an individual generally goes alone, to read, do work/homework or use the computer.

English is not my native language, and all the usual words seem wrong somehow.

- Office sounds too professional/clerical.  "Step into my office..."
- Study sounds too academic / Sherlock Holmes.
- Not enough books to be a library.
- Not enough couches to be a den.
- Not public enough to be a lounge.
- Not enough mini-fridges to be a man-cave.
- Only goes downhill from there...

I realize I'm probably overthinking this and I should just go with office, but I'm curious what everyone will think/answer.

Thanks.

Comment: You've already identified a number of common valid words. There's no single 'right' answer to this because not everyone has the same setup at home nor uses similar spaces in the same way. If I run a business from home then I'll have an office, if I'm a fan of Victorian fiction then I'll retreat to my study, etc., etc.

Comment: For someone who is not a native English speaker, that is a very nicely written question.

Comment: I call mine “an ***office***”.  It is not too professional/clerical.  It’s what everyone I know calls it.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I've voted to close as primarily opinion-based, because you've ruled out all the obvious answers (*office*, *study*, *library*, *den*) out of your personal dislike of the terms, as opposed to what the general public would use, and Stack Exchange is not a suggestion engine or a guessing game. Depending on the kind of work done there it could also be a *studio*, *workspace*, *salon*, and [any number of other things](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/rooms-found-in-the-home).

Comment: I agree with Jim. I only ever use my home "office" for working or browsing on the computer or playing the digital piano that's in the room. Reading I do everywhere.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What an excellent list! I would say either "study" or "office", depending on the intended use of the room. The former implies a bit of coziness, perhaps a comfortable chair, a place where you can relax and read a book. The latter is more businesslike, with a desk: a room where you might pay your bills or work on your taxes.

"My office" does sound a little pretentious, so I would say "the office" if context makes it clear that you are talking about a room in your house and not the place where you are employed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to the room in question as a ***[study(room)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/study)***

> a room, especially in a house, used for quiet work such as reading or writing.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

[image]

(Hometone.com)

Answer (score -1):

My brother refers to his "office", which I think sounds a little pretentious. Also, "office" to me sounds a bit too work-related for a place you're going to read and, hopefully, relax. Personally, I like the idea of a cozy "study", as in: "he retreated to his study". I don't smoke, but if I did I would definitely retreat to my wood panelled study to unwind, take a pipe and enjoy a glass of vintage port. A lounge needn't be public, by the way. In the English Midlands where I come from, the best room in our little two bed semi was referred to as the lounge.

Comment: "home office" is common, but "office" without the modifier suggests something more formal.

Comment: This use of lounge (= living room, parlour) is British English.